# How to create multiple tables in html based on json data in Angular using web API

Tags: angular, ngfor

How to create multiple tables in html based on JSON data in Angular using web API

Please find below json response code, Example i want to show below data in 2 tables based on date. If i search 3 dates(12-08-2021, 13-08-2021 and 14-08-2021)it should show in 3 tables.

**API Response code:**

```
    {
  "12-08-2021": [
    {
      "id": "121",
      "task_website": "www.xyz.com",
      "task_id": "P-4234",
      "task_desc": "static page",
      "task_status": "completed",
      "start_time": "22:50",
      "end_time": "23:50",
      "task_time": "1",
      "report_date": "12-08-2021"
    },
    {
      "id": "122",
      "task_website": "www.abc.com",
      "task_id": "P-4235",
      "task_desc": "dynamic page",
      "task_status": "completed",
      "start_time": "23:50",
      "end_time": "12:50",
      "task_time": "11",
      "report_date": "12-08-2021"
    }
  ],
  "13-08-2021": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "task_website": "www.abc.com",
      "task_id": "P-4234",
      "task_desc": "static page",
      "task_status": "completed",
      "start_time": "23:51",
      "end_time": "12:51",
      "task_time": "11",
      "report_date": "13-08-2021"
    },
    {
      "id": "124",
      "task_website": "www.xyz.com",
      "task_id": "P-4234",
      "task_desc": "dynamic page",
      "task_status": "completed",
      "start_time": "12:52",
      "end_time": "15:52",
      "task_time": "3",
      "report_date": "13-08-2021"
    }
  ]
}
```

**search.component.html**

```
    <table id="excel-table" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Project Name</th>
                  <th>Project ID</th>
                  <th>Activity</th>
                  <th>Start Time</th>
                  <th>End Time</th>
                  <th>Billable Hours</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let report of reports">
                    <td>{{report.task_website}}</td>
                    <td>{{report.task_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{report.task_desc}}</td>
                    <td>{{report.start_time}}</td>
                    <td>{{report.end_time}}</td>
                    <td>{{report.task_time}}</td>
                    <td>{{report.report_date}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

**search.component.ts**

```
searchdata() {  
    this._service.searchdata(this.search).subscribe((res: any) => {  
        this.reports=res;  
        var separate={};
        for(var row of res) {
          if(separate.hasOwnProperty(row.report_date)){
            separate[row.report_date].push(row);
          } else {
            separate[row.report_date] = [row];
          }
        }
        console.log(separate);  
    })  
  }
```

Table wants to create based on date.
Expected Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eybhp.png
Current Output : https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6hUg.png

Comment: what your console.log shows

Comment: Below API response code : 12-08-2021: Array(2)
    0: {id: '121', task_website: 'www.xyz.com', task_id: 'P-4234', task_desc: 'static page', task_status: 'completed', …}
    1: {id: '122', task_website: 'www.abc.com', task_id: 'P-4235', task_desc: 'dynamic page', task_status: 'completed', …}
    
    13-08-2021: Array(2)
    0: {id: '123', task_website: 'www.abc.com', task_id: 'P-4234', task_desc: 'static page', task_status: 'completed', …}
    1: {id: '124', task_website: 'www.xyz.com', task_id: 'P-4234', task_desc: 'dynamic page', task_status: 'completed', …}

Comment: you should use another *ngFor on your table for separating table base on date.

Comment: @kian tried, but not working.  Could you please tell how to do that ? Because i am new to angular.

Answer (score 0):

I just used Object.entries for getting object values(how many date you want) and make tables base on this.
Then make table rows base on array's second child (first child is object key and second is values).

**search.component.ts**

```
searchdata() {  
  this._service.searchdata(this.search).subscribe((res: any) => {  
    this.reports= Object.entries(res);
  })                                                                        
}
```

**search.component.html**

```
  <table id="excel-table" class="table table-striped" *ngFor="let table of reports">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Project Name</th>
            <th>Project ID</th>
            <th>Activity</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>End Time</th>
            <th>Billable Hours</th>
            <th>Date</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr *ngFor="let report of table[1]">
           <td>{{report.task_website}}</td>
           <td>{{report.task_id}}</td>
           <td>{{report.task_desc}}</td>
           <td>{{report.start_time}}</td>
           <td>{{report.end_time}}</td>
           <td>{{report.task_time}}</td>
           <td>{{report.report_date}}</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried with above code, it's returning column names only  "Project Name Project ID Activity Start Time End Time Billable Hours Date" not the result.